# How to obtain the relative position (coordinates) of SIFT feature from image center coordinates?

Tags: image-processing, image-segmentation, sift

I have extracted SIFT features (keypoints and descriptors) of training set and saved in an inverted index form.

My question is how can I calculate the coordinates of each visual features in an image from the center point? I need this information to calculate a similarity between query image and retrieved training images.

I really appreciate your help.

Comment: It sounds like it would come down to however you determine the center point of whatever blobular feature you're looking at. It'd be helpful if you could provide some sample data and/or images.

Comment: I found the answer of my question in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35884409/how-to-extract-x-y-coordinates-from-opencv-cv2-keypoint-object)

Answer (score 0):

`point.pt is a tuple` (x,y)`.

So,

```
x = point.pt[0]
y = point.pt[1]
```

or,

```
(x,y) = point.pt
```